# How can I set a mapping for <C-S-m> in Windows terminal?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I'd like to remap `<C-S-m>` to insert  `|>` at the cursor:

```
vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, "i", "<C-S-m>", " |>", {})
```

This works on macOS using iterm2, but using Windows Terminal on Windows 11 I get this weird thing which I've never seen before:

[image]

Other key combinations that don't use ctrl + shift, e.g. `<C-m>`, work fine. `<C-M>` seems to be equivalent to `<C-m>`, but not to `<C-S-m>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue of mapping `<C-S-m>` in windows terminal with Nvim, you need to bind `<C-S-m>` by using the `sendInput` command in Windows Terminal's `settings.json`. It will send a specific escape sequence when `<C-S-m>` is pressed. I prefer you to see this github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/406).
you can add these lines in your windows terminal's `settings.json`

```json
{
    "command": {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "\u001b[EscapeSequence]"
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+shift+m"
}
```

You need to replace `"\u001b[EscapeSequence]"` with the actual escape sequence that Nvim expects for inserting `|>`. You may need to experiment with different sequences. I can't check it since I'm not using windows